# Python: datetime.date "expected datetime, got int"

Tags: python, datetime, typeerror

So, for a long time now, I have been using code like the following in Python for version tracking:

```
...
import datetime
...

"""
Version tracking
"""
__version__ = 4.0
__dateV__ = datetime.date(2015, 5, 7)
...
```

Now, out of the blue, I get an error saying "TypeError: descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'"

This has never happened before, and the documentation for the datetime module says that a "date" object should be initialized with year, month, and day arguments, which are all INTEGERS.

I have confirmed that I am using Python version 2.7.

Has anyone else seen this error? This is literally at the top of my code (right after all of the imports.) Please help.

Comment: Please post a complete, self-contained example demonstrating the problem.  I suspect you actually have `from datetime import datetime`.

Comment: I agree with BrenBarn I can reproduce the error if I do `import datetime as dt dt.datetime.date(2014,1,1)`

Comment: You get this error from **`typing.Optional` or `typing.Union`?** the issue is the bad import because `import datetime` results in `datetime` being a  ***module***, whereas `from datetime import datetime` results in `datetime` being ***type*** - and `typing` only accepts ***ŧypes*** :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon closer inspection, I have found that the root cause of the error was actually in one of my import statements.

One of my modules had an error in it, but for some reason that error was not caught until the line **dateV** = datetime.date(5, 7, 2015)

The datetime module was imported correctly, but the traceback sent me on a wild goose chase. Commenting out the imports of the faulty modules got rid of the error.

Comment: are you using a wild-card (`*`) import by any chance? It may explain why importing from some other module may break `datetime.date` call.

Comment: Yes, that was indeed what I had been doing. I have made sure to only import the specific classes I need from said modules, and the problem has gone away.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments above have suggested, you've probably imported with

```
from datetime import datetime
```

That is, the name `datetime` will refer to the class `datetime` representing a date and time together (imported from the `datetime` module, which, annoyingly, has the same name).

Then, `date` is a method for retrieving the date-part of a `datetime` object:

```
In [4]: my_date = datetime(2015,5,7,20,02,00)
In [5]: my_date.date()
In [6]: datetime.date(2015, 5, 7)
```

It doesn't take any arguments (see [the source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/datetime.py#l1466)) apart from `self`, so if you call it with one or more integer arguments, it complains:

```
In [7]: datetime.date(999)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-55d65eb13663> in <module>()
----> 1 datetime.date(999)

TypeError: descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'
```

In this context, `datetime.date` is the method of a `datetime` object and doesn't know what to do with `999`. The following are equivalent:

```
In [8]: datetime.date(my_date)
Out[8]: datetime.date(2015, 5, 7)

In [9]: my_date.date()
Out[9]: datetime.date(2015, 5, 7)
```

---

If you import the `datetime` *module*, you can do what you want because `date` is also the name of a class (for representing dates without hours, minutes, etc) within this module:

```
In [1]: import datetime
In [2]: datetime.date(2015, 5, 7)    # OK, returns a date object
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using `from datetime import *:

```
>>> from datetime import *
>>> date = datetime.date(2015, 5, 7)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'
```

Use`from datetime import date` then:

```
>>> date = date(2015, 5, 7)
```

Comment: `from datetime import date` does *not* introduce `datetime` name therefore you should get NameError here.

Comment: start `python`, put your code from the answer, see what happens